# How to hide/toggle legends with layer controls in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, leaflet, layers, legend

In the package `leaflet` for R, you have the ability to toggle layers on and off with the `addLayersControl()` option. If you use legends for each individual layer, however, these layers are **not** toggled on and off with the layers control. Here's a quick reproducible example of what I'm working with:

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

#load in shapefiles, trim excess data
gtm <- getData('GADM', country = 'GTM', level = 0)
gtm <- gtm[, -c(2:68)]

mex <- getData('GADM', country = 'MEX', level = 0)
mex <- mex[, -c(2:68)]


leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data = gtm, 
              fillColor = 'red', 
              group = "gtm") %>% 
  addLegend(color = "red",
            labels = gtm@data$OBJECTID) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = mex, 
              fillColor = 'blue', 
              group = "mex") %>% 
  addLegend(color = "blue", 
            labels = mex@data$OBJECTID) %>% 
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("gtm", "mex"), 
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F))][1]][1]
```

[image]

As you can see above, when I toggle the Mexico layer off, its legend remains. [I've searched the question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=%5bleaflet%5dlegend%20layer) a bit, but all of the questions appear to be applicable to Leaflet.js rather than the R package. Is there any way to control the legends in Leaflet for R so that they can also toggle on and off?

Comment: Here's a couple of things you could try: Add your layers to a group layer (see https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html), or check the issues page on Github (https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=legend) for issues related to legend display. If you don't see an issue related to your problem then you could create a new one with the info you've provided above; it looks like they are still in active development so they may respond quickly.

Comment: @Lauren, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can add legend to the same group, then it will show/hide legend and polygons both. Learn more [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html).

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

#load in shapefiles
gtm <- getData('GADM', country = 'GTM', level = 0)
mex <- getData('GADM', country = 'MEX', level = 0)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data = gtm, 
              fillColor = 'red', 
              group = "gtm") %>% 
  addLegend(color = "red",
            labels = gtm@data$GID_0, 
            group = "gtm") %>% 

  addPolygons(data = mex, 
              fillColor = 'blue', 
              group = "mex") %>% 
  addLegend(color = "blue", 
        labels = mex@data$GID_0,
        group = "mex") %>% 

  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("gtm", "mex"), 
               options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F))
```

Answer (score 2):

We solved this by controlling layer visibility with a shiny switch input and manually clearing the group and removing the legend:

`map %>% clearGroup("zones") %>% removeControl("zonesLegend")`

If you're not using shiny you can [add some custom JS with htmlwidgets::onRender](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html#custom-javascript-with-htmlwidgetonrender) that listens for changes to the layer control and removes the appropriate controls.